# Nginx, How To Allow HTTPS In IP With Different Port?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to make HTTPS on IP with different PORT on NGINX server??

I'm having a problem with this I understand how to create an IP with a port but I don't understand how to make the IP with this port use HTTPS properly. Please help.

I'm trying to make a website with this IP domain looks like.

```
http://138.51.151.51:8888 >> https://138.51.151.51:8888
```

What i already do for ssl but the test was turn to be failed

```
server {

listen 8888 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:8888 default_server;



ssl                  on;
ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certificate.crt; 
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private.key;


server_name  138.51.151.51;
access_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
location     / {
root         /home/www/html;
index        index.html;
}
```

[image: this is what my problem]

Comment: The error indicates a different configuration file. Have you determined the reason that’s the case? This configuration file would have a reference to *0.0.0.0*

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you’re trying to achieve. Are you simply trying to add a HTTPS listener on a different port? // The error message is quite clear: You have multiple `default_server`s and they’re conflicting somehow.